# Persistent warning when using play command of DisTube

Tags: node.js, discord.js, warnings, distube

My code's working but I keep getting the same warning which is :

> WARNING: @distube/ytsr is out of date! Update with "npm install
> @distube/ytsr@latest".

I tried installing `@distube/ytsr@latest` as it's said but I keep getting the warning.

Also, the warning also appears when I launch my code with `"node --no-warnings main.js"`

It's not really a big trouble but I'd still like to solve it.

Comment: What exactly is your ytsr version please (writton on package.json)?

Comment: Here's all I have :

{
  "dependencies": {
    "@distube/ytdl-core": "^4.13.3",
    "@distube/ytsr": "^2.0.0",
    "avconv": "^3.1.0",
    "discord.js": "^14.14.1",
    "distube": "^4.1.1",
    "ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^5.2.0",
    "libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.13",
    "opusscript": "^0.0.8",
    "ytsr": "^3.8.4"
  }
}

Comment: Did you try deleting all of node_modules and all of the dependencies on your package.json file (you would have "dependencies" : {}), then reintalling only discord.js and @distube/ytsr@latest? Because there is nowhere in the github repo code this "text" that distube is out of date (when you have the last version) so maybe it's npm not knowing you have the latest version or confusing it with the actual distube package instead of the lightweight actual package you're using

Comment: Okay so I've tried deleting the dependencies of the package.json and the package-lock.json files but weirdly my bot is still working and still playing music. So I've made a new draft where I just install @distube/ytsr@latest and discord js (and distube) and put a little piece of code in order to make my bot play music. And the warning is still there.
It's getting weirder and weirder and I'm not really good with all that stuff so I guess that I'm going to just let the Warning for now and maybe try again when I'll be more experimented. But if you ever get the solution I'd like to know it :)

Answer (score 0):

From [@distube/ytsr npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@distube/ytsr#update-checks), you can actually set the environment variable `YTSR_NO_UPDATE` to `1` to disable the update check.

You can also set the variable directly like this before your Distube initialization

```js
process.env.YTSR_NO_UPDATE = "1";
```